# What is the difference between async Task and Task

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

For example, what is the difference between this code:

```
public async Task DoSomething(int aqq)
{
    await DoAnotherThingAsync(aqq);
}
```

and this one:

```
public Task DoSomething(int aqq)
{
    DoAnotherThingAsync(aqq);
}
```

Are they both correct?

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate. The other question isn't *exactly* the same as yours, but the answer applies just as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both signatures are correct, if used properly.

`async Task` allows you to use await keyword inside your method. The first example is totally OK.

The second example missing return statement:

```
public Task DoSomething(int aqq)
{
   return DoAnotherThingAsync(aqq);
}
```

Going with second signature you cannot use await keyword, but still you can return some task, that you got from somwhere else, for example, `Task.FromResult(true);`

To give you another difference consider the example:

```
public async Task DoSomething1(int aqq)
{
    await DoAnotherThingAsync(aqq); //blocks here and wait DoAnotherThingAsync to respond
    SomethingElse();
}


public Task DoSomething2(int aqq)
{
    var task = DoAnotherThingAsync(aqq); //keep going here, not waiting for anything
    SomethingElse();
    return task;
}

public async Task DoAnotherThingAsync(int aqq)
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
}

public void SomethingElse()
{
    //do something
}
```

If you are using async/await you are actually waiting the task to complete. Returning a task doesn't wait for the task to be completed.

Answer (score 1):

In your sample, no. Your second method breaks the task chain, which is entirely wrong and can cause hard to find bugs and weird behaviour overall.

You need to *return* the task if you're not using `async` (which handles the return for you automagically).

There's also some subtle differences that are important when debugging and a few other gotchas, but that's quite a broad topic :) Until you understand the issue perfectly, just use async and await - they are the highest level tool available in C# at this point.

Answer (score -3):

Yeah, they both correct, but second is better.

Async keyword is just a syntaxic sugar that allow us to write linear code instead of strange style of manual handling tasks.

First variant is compiled into state machine and it results that it takes a bit more time than second variant. You even can rewrite first variant to `return Task.Run(() => DoAnotherThingAsync(aqq).Result)` to get idea where is the difference. Note: this is just an idea, instead rewriting of first method is more complex. I just want to show you that your variants not similar.

You can read more about how async works in the article ["Async Await and the Generated StateMachine"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/535635/Async-Await-and-the-Generated-StateMachine)

Comment: You're right that the first case will be rewritten into a state machine and that it has a cost (of course, if you're dealing with real I/O code, this cost is most likely tiny compared to the work you're trying to do, but okay). However, there's no similarity between using `Task.Run` and `await`, that's just entirely misleading. Either clarify what you're trying to say, or get rid of the claim.

Comment: @Luaan yeah, you are correct. Added clarification to prevent misleading.